# Replace One Letter of Text with a new value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a situation where in the 7th position of a field ex:(125283B00), I would like to replace the text value with the letter 'V'.
I have tried a simple replace which works fine (replace(somecolumn, 'B', 'V')) however, I am having to nest the replace to account for the different letters that exist.
Am I overlooking an easier method to identify if the 7th character is a letter and if so, replace it with the letter 'V' ?

Thanks

This works fine but I don't like that it's hard-coded. Would prefer it to identify the 7th position as a letter and replace it with 'V' if it is in fact a letter

```
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(pi.kprintitem, 'B', 'V'), 'H', 'V'), 'G', 'V'), 'M', 'V'),'K','V') AS Item
```

Comment: Please tag the DBMS you're using. Especially as String-Manipulation differs quite a bit between the available products.

Comment: Thanks but, I believe I tagged it with SQL.

Comment: You need to tag the DBMS (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.)

Comment: you may benefit from REGEX_REPLACE if available in your environemnt

Comment: Does [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) do what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT STUFF('125283B00', 7, 1, 'V');
```

[image]

P.S. just want to enhance it. if you need to replace just only a specific latter such as B to update to V

```
declare @val varchar(15) = '125283B00'

SELECT 
    case Substring(@val, 7,1) 
        when 'B' then STUFF(@val, 7, 1, 'V')
    else @val end
```

in addition, if you want to replace ANY non digit char in 7th position to V you can use regex pattern

```
SELECT 
    case 
        when Substring(@val, 7,1) not like '%[0-9]%' then STUFF(@val, 7, 1, 'V')
    else @val end
```

Comment: Thanks..I was able to leverage what you suggested.


CASE
        WHEN len(pi.kprintitem) < 7 THEN
            pi.kprintitem
        WHEN substring(pi.kprintitem, 7, 1) NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN
            stuff(pi.kprintitem, 7, 1, 'V')
        ELSE
            pi.kprintitem

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) :

```
UPDATE mytable
SET col = substring(col, 1, 6) + 'V' + substring(col, 8, 3)              
WHERE substring(col, 7, 1) = 'B'
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/_iK83wnZ)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you're selecting data and you want to affect qualifying rows in the resultset, or you want to update the base table.

If the former you could try:

```
select Iif(c like '%[0-9]%', col, Stuff(col, 7, 1, 'V'))
from t
cross apply(values(Substring(col, 7, 1)))c(c);
```

Comment: nice slick approach.